# CardScrollView library for android

Tags: android, android-layout, cardlayout

Tried this link to develop the Card Layout but I didn't got any jar file from the source site.

[Here is the link for the Card Layout](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/ui-widgets)

Please help me in getting the jar file for card layout in eclipse kepler instead of android studio.

When I am trying with the code it was unable to import the things related to cardview.

Comment: pls check this link https://github.com/Androguide/cardsui-for-android

Comment: But those link refers to third party libraries. I need the L Priview